# Segmenting letters in a Captcha image

Tags: python, image-processing, captcha, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I've written this algorithm in Python for reading CAPTCHAs using scikit-image:

```
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage import io

def process(self, image):
    """
    Processes a CAPTCHA by removing noise

    Args:
        image (str): The file path of the image to process
    """

    input = io.imread(image)
    histogram = {}

    for x in range(input.shape[0]):
        for y in range(input.shape[1]):
            pixel = input[x, y]
            hex = '%02x%02x%02x' % (pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2])

            if hex in histogram:
                histogram[hex] += 1
            else:
                histogram[hex] = 1

    histogram = sorted(histogram, key = histogram.get, reverse=True)
    threshold = len(histogram) * 0.015

    for x in range(input.shape[0]):
        for y in range(input.shape[1]):
            pixel = input[x, y]
            hex = '%02x%02x%02x' % (pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2])
            index = histogram.index(hex)

            if index < 3 or index > threshold:
                input[x, y] = [255, 255, 255, 255]

    input = rgb2gray(~input)
    io.imsave(image, input)
```

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

It works fairly well and I get decent results after running it through Google's Tesseract OCR, but I want to make it better. I think that straightening the letters would yield a much better result. My question is how do I do that?

I understand I need to box the letters somehow, like so:

[image: Boxed]

Then, for each character, rotate it some number of degrees based on a vertical or horizontal line.

My initial thought was to identify the center of a character (possibly by finding clusters of most used colors in the histogram) and then expanding a box until it found black, but again, I'm not so sure how to go about doing that.

What are some common practices used in image segmentation to achieve this result?

**Edit:**

In the end, further refining the color filters and limiting Tesseract to only characters yielded a nearly 100% accurate result without any deskewing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate for http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ or http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hmm.. Noted. Could we instead move it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operation you want to do is technically in computer vision known as deskewing of the objects, for this you have to apply a geometric transformation on the objects, i have a snippet of the code to do apply deskewing on objects (binary). here is the code(uses opencv library):

```
def deskew(image, width):
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    moments = cv2.moments(image)
    skew = moments["mu11"] / moments["mu02"]
    M = np.float32([[1, skew, -0.5 * w * skew],[0, 1, 0]])
    image = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), flags = cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv2.INTER_LINEAR) 
    return image
```

Comment: OpenCV seems a lot more useful than any other module for this application, but they don't support Python 3 just yet. Thank you for this. I still need a method for finding the areas to deskew.

Comment: What is an image moment?

Comment: open cv 3 support had come for python 3, check their website for further details, you don not need to find specific areas for deskewing, you just have to send each bounding rectangle as an image to input of the method and if letter is aligned in any orientation it automatically finds proper deskew coefficient, if letter is properly aligned it will not change its geometry. Second an image moment is a certain particular weighted average (moment) of the image pixels' intensities or pixel indices, or a function of such moments, usually chosen to have some attractive property or interpretation.

Comment: ``skimage.moments.regionprops`` will give you the moments.  The deskewing can be done with ``skimage.transform``, using the same idea Ankit mentions above.

Comment: I have the regions to deskew provided from the `regionprops` function. I was able to draw boxes around them as I described above using `draw.line`. I see there is a `transform.AffineTransform`. Assuming that is the transform I want, how do I put these two together?

Comment: I don't understand what "mu11" and "mu02" are and how dividing them gives you a skew (vector?). I think that "M" is the same thing as the coordinate map in skimage, but I do not know how to derive that.